# Sequence Objects in Custom Functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I trying to get next value from 4 sequences conditionally (by parameter). In custom scalar valued function i tried to use "next value for Sequence". Sequence defined as

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[sequence1] 
 AS [int]
 START WITH 1
 INCREMENT BY 1
 MINVALUE -2147483648
 MAXVALUE 2147483647
 CACHE 
GO
```

And function defined as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetConditionalNextCounterValue
(
    @CounterID tinyint
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

   DECLARE @Counter AS INT

   -- IF CounterID=1 then return value from Sequence1
   IF (@CounterID = 1)
   BEGIN
     set @Counter = next value for sequence1;
   END

   IF (@CounterID = **2**)
   BEGIN
     set @Counter = next value for sequence2;
   END

   RETURN @Counter

END
```

BUT customs functions are not supporting "next value for Sequence". 
Error is: NEXT VALUE FOR function is not allowed in check constraints, default objects, computed columns, views, user-defined functions, user-defined aggregates, user-defined table types, sub-queries, common table expressions, or derived tables.

Is any workaround/other way available to achieve this?

Comment: . . Perhaps you can use a stored procedure instead of a function.  You can return the value as an output parameter.