# conditional "next value for sequence"

Tags: sql-server

scenario:

Sql Server 2012 Table named "Test" has two fields. "CounterNo" and "Value" both integers.

There are 4 sequence objects defined named sq1, sq2, sq3, sq4

I want to do these on inserts:

- if CounterNo = **1** then Value = next value for **sq1**
- if CounterNo = **2** then Value = next value for **sq2**
- if CounterNo = **3** then Value = next value for **sq3**

I think, create a custom function assign it as default value of Value field. But when i tried custom functions not supports "next value for Sequence Objects"

Another way is using trigger. That table has trigger already.

Using a Stored Procedure for Inserts is the best way. But EntityFramework 5 Code-First is not supporting it.

Can you suggest me a way to achieve this.

(if you show me how can i do it with custom functions [you can also post it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683038/sequence-objects-in-custom-functions). It's another question of me.)

**Update:**
In reality there are 23 fields in that table and also primary keys setted and i'm generating this counter value on software side, using "counter table".It is not good to generate counter values on client side.

I'm using 4 sequence objects as counters because they represents different types of records.

If i use 4 counters on same record at same time, all of them generates next values. I want  only related counter generates it's next value while others remains same.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not shure if I fully understand your use case but maybe the following sample illustrates what you need.

```
Create Table Vouchers (
    Id              uniqueidentifier    Not Null Default NewId()
    , Discriminator varchar(100)        Not Null
    , VoucherNumber int                 Null
    -- ...
    , MoreData      nvarchar(100)       Null
);
go
Create Sequence InvoiceSequence AS int Start With 1 Increment By 1;
Create Sequence OrderSequence AS int Start With 1 Increment By 1;
go
Create Trigger TR_Voucher_Insert_VoucherNumer On Vouchers After Insert As 
   If Exists (Select 1 From inserted Where Discriminator = 'Invoice')
     Update v
        Set VoucherNumber = Next Value For InvoiceSequence
        From Vouchers v Inner Join inserted i On (v.Id = i.Id)
        Where i.Discriminator = 'Invoice';
   If Exists (Select 1 From inserted Where Discriminator = 'Order')
     Update v
        Set VoucherNumber = Next Value For OrderSequence
        From Vouchers v Inner Join inserted i On (v.Id = i.Id)
        Where i.Discriminator = 'Order';
go

Insert Into Vouchers (Discriminator, MoreData) 
Values ('Invoice', 'Much')
    ,  ('Invoice', 'More')
    ,  ('Order', 'Data')
    ,  ('Invoice', 'And')
    ,  ('Order', 'Again')
;
go

Select * From Vouchers;
```

Now Invoice- and Order-Numbers will be incremented independently. And as you can have multiple insert triggers on the same table, that shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're thinking about this in the wrong way. You have 3 values and these values are determined by another column. Switch it around, create 3 columns and remove the `Counter` column.

If you have a table with `value1`, `value2` and `value3` then the `Counter` value is implied by the column in which the value resides. Create a unique index on these three columns and add an identity column for a primary key and you're sorted; you can do it all in a stored procedure easily.

Comment: Thank you, you are saying generate 3 value and choose in software side if i understand correctly. I clarify situation as editing my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have four different types of records, use four different tables, with a separate `identity` column in each one.

If you need to see all the data together, then use a view to combine them:

```
create v_AllTypes as
    select * from type1 union all
    select * from type2 union all
    select * from type3 union all
    select * from type4;
```

Alternatively, do the calculation of the sequence number on output:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by CounterNo order by t.id) as TypeSeqNum
from AllTypes t;
```

Something seems amiss with your data model if it requires conditional updates to four identity columns.

Comment: And I prefer to use Sql Server 2012 Sequence Objects over row_number()